# How does AudioKit add a filter to the microphone?

Tags: audiokit

I wrote this, but I still can't filter the frequencies above 100 Hz.

```
microphone = AKMicrophone()
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(microphone, hopSize: 200.0, peakCount: 2000.0)

lowFilter = AKLowPassFilter.init(microphone, cutoffFrequency: 100.0, resonance: 0)
silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
AudioKit.output = silence

try!AudioKit.start()
lowFilter.start()
microphone.play()
tracker.start()
```